# How to Insert The Color Picker Without Using Show Dialog In Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc, color-picker

i just want to insert the color picker without using show dialog and setState because im using bloc provider. and i dont know how to call a color picker

```
Container(
              width: 300,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: const [
                  Text (
                    'LED Color',
                    style:TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: ColorPicker(
                      pickerColor : pickerColor,
                      onColorChange: changeColor,
                    ),
                  )
                  // SingleChildScrollView(
                  //     child: ColorPicker(
                  //       pickerColor: pickerColor,
                  //       onColorChange: changeColor
                  //     )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: What is the issue with current snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ColorPicker is a widget place on any place. It is not mandatory to place on dialog.

```dart
class ASDXf extends StatefulWidget {
  const ASDXf({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ASDXf> createState() => _ASDXfState();
}

class _ASDXfState extends State<ASDXf> {
  Color selectedColor = Colors.purple;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: 300,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              color: selectedColor,
            ),
            const Text(
              'LED Color',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ColorPicker(
                pickerColor: selectedColor,
                onColorChanged: (value) {
                  selectedColor = value;
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: im not using setState , because im using bloc provider. so it does not work. :'(

Comment: Can you include minimal  full snippet , yes you can convert setSate to bloc